# Can not connect to FTP even when the code is correct and the firewall is down

Tags: php, ftp

Every time I try to connect to the FTP server, it fails

When I write "ftp://storage.xxx.xxx/" in the browser, it works.

But when I try with php code, it fails - which is why I have tried different combinations, but without success.

What caused the error? Why can not I connect? It must be said that the firewall is turned off.

```
     $ftp_server1 = "storage.xxx.xxx/";  
     $ftp_server2 = "ftp.storage.xxx.xxx"; 
     $ftp_server3 = "ftp://storage.xxx.xxx";



$ftp_username   = "xxx";
$ftp_password   =  "xxx";
//setup of connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server2,21) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");
```

Answer (score 0):

try `ftp_connect($ftp_username . ':' . $ftp_password . '@' . $ftp_server, 21);`

make sure `$ftp_server` is the correct address, omitting `ftp://` as per the `ftp_connect()` docs, e.g. `$ftp_server = 'storage.xxx.xxx';`. it appears you have been including this in your tests.